# anchor tag doesn't submit items to cart python django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a dashboard of items displayed from my `uniform` model. I am attempting to send the item to a cart for checking out the item. I am not having issues loading my internal server, and I am getting no debugging issues. But when looking at my admin Order Item model, nothing has been pushed to it:

**urls.py**

```
from apparelapp import views
...

# TEMPLATE URLS
app_name = 'apparelapp'
urlpatterns = [
...
path('add_to_cart/<slug>/', views.add_to_cart, name="add_to_cart"),
...
]
```

**views.py**

```
# add to cart
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Uniform, slug=slug)
    order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(item = uniform)
    order_qs = Transaction.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]

        if transaction.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()

        else:
            transaction.item.add(item)

    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Transaction.objects.create(user=request.user, ordered_date = ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)

    messages.success(request, "Added to cart!")
    return redirect('apparelapp:item_list')
```

**models.py**

```
#OrderItem
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    uniform = models.OneToOneField(Uniform, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default = 1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uniform.description

#Item
class Uniform(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=11)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length = 6)
    size = models.CharField(choices=CLOTHES_SIZE, max_length=4, blank=True)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, max_length=15, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uniforms/')
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['category']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {} - {} - ${}'.format(self.category, self.description, self.size, self.price)

    def add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("apparelapp:add_to_cart", slug=slug)
```

**html**

```
<h2>List of items</h2>

<section class="text-center mb-4">

  <div class="row wow fadeIn">
    {% for item in object_list %}
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="view overlay">
                    <img src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="Oh no!" width="200" height="200">
                    <a>
                        <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <label>
                        <h5>{{ item.description }}</h5>
                    </label>
                    <h5>
                        {% if object.description %}
                        <strong>
                            <label for="">{{ item.category }}</label>
                        </strong>
                        {% endif %}
                    </h5>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-2">
                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Size</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-10">
                          <a href="{{ object.get_add_to_cart_url}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Initially I tried out the button once adding an item and it worked, but wouldn't add any additinoal items, now the link doesn't work as a whole. Am I missing something in my `views.py`?

Comment: please, add `urlpatterns` from `urls.py` file of your project, where you have url to go for to add item to cart.

Comment: @PythonNewbie I made that update. I am working with the slug of the item and nothing has been  pushed through and no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use `name` attribute of `path` element of your `urlpatterns` list to navigate through project without changing url itself, if needed. To use this feature, you can specify [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) with syntax like:

`{{ url '<name_of_path_element>' arg1=arg.data }}`

Where  is `name` attribute of `path` element of your `urlpatterns`, like I said above; and arg1 is **not required** argument to pass as [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), and, arg.data is data to be passed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <a href="{{ url 'add_to_cart' slug=item.slug }}" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
</div>
```

---

Please, let me know if it doesn't work.